# Add a HTML input to a Symfony 2 form

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony, twig

I'm creating a custom form using Symfony2. I created the "first part" of the form using Symfony as the following code:

```js
class TelemedidaMecanicaLecturaType extends AbstractType{
    
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('fecha')
                ->add('valor')
        ;
    }
}
```

Then, in the Twig template I need to add three extra fields: the submit button and two hidden inputs that I need to get some important information.
I tried to do that:

```html
<form method="post" id="FormLec{{um.id}}">
            {{ form_widget(formLecArr[um.um]) }}
            <input type="hidden" name="um" value="{{um.id}}"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="telemedidaMecanica" value="{{telemedidaMecanica.id}}"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Crear"/>
        </form>
```

But when I send the form, and I try to get data from the controller, I only get "fecha" and "valor" values. It is strange, because missing fields are displayed in the HTML text (using inspect code utility in chrome) and the submit button works correctly.
Where is the "um" and "telemedidaMecanica" values?
What I am doing wrong?

Thank you!
Isaac.

Comment: You need to add all form fields to the FormType or they get ignored. Is there a reason why you can't get those values in the Type and set them as the default values there. If not, you could place them elsewhere in the template and set them after load using jQuery or some such but that's a bit of a backwards way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is pass all form fields to the FormType when you are creating the form. The submit button only posts the values which were generated from the Formbuilder.

You can do something like this:

```
class TelemedidaMecanicaLecturaType extends AbstractType{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('fecha')
                ->add('valor')
                ->add('um','hidden')
                ->add('telemedidaMecanica','hidden')
        ;
    }
}
```

*Alternatively*, if you don't have access to these variables in your Entity itself, you can pass the values when you instantiate your FormBuilder from your Controller itself.

Something like this in your controller would work:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new TelemedidaMecanicaLecturaType($um, $telemedidaMecanica);
```

and then in your FormBuilder you can take advantage of [data](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#data) property of the form. Do this:

```
class TelemedidaMecanicaLecturaType extends AbstractType{

    private $um;
    private $telemedidaMecanica;

    public function __construct($um, $telemedidaMecanica)
    {
        $this->um= $um;
        $this->telemedidaMecanica= $telemedidaMecanica;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('fecha')
                ->add('valor')
                ->add('um','hidden', array('data' => $this->um, 'mapped' => false))
                ->add('telemedidaMecanica','hidden', array('data' => $this->telemedidaMecanica, 'mapped' => false))
        ;
    }
}
```

This will post hidden values too when you click Submit.

Comment: Just don't forget to add for those fields 'mapped' => false if they are not part of the entity

Comment: I don't know how could I have forgotten to include that. Thanks @Stmm

Comment: Thank you :)
Add fields to the FormType was sollution!